# Automatic \fullcite for entries whose keywords field includes a certain keyword

Tags: biblatex, citing, automation

For a thesis, I would like to switch the behaviour of the citation commands  `\cite` and `\footcite` based on the cited entry's keywords, so that Biblatex automatically outputs the citations of source texts (as opposed to cited literature) throughout the text using the bibliography driver for the respective entry type to create a full citation similar to the bibliography entry (basically a `\fullcite` or `\footfullcite`).

The `.tex`-file with the text is generated using [multimarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) (and some subsequent regular expressions) and all citations are created using the `\cite` or `\footcite`-command.

Source texts are `.bib`-file entries whose `keywords` field includes a certain keyword ("quelle"), which is also used to generate a separate bibliography for the source texts using the `keyword` option of Biblatex's `\printbibliography` command.

Is there a way to do this automatically using Biblatex-features?

Why do I need this?:

- When citing sources using a shorthand is often not appropriate, because more information (e.g. date and recipient of a letter) is needed directly in the context of the text.
- With separated bibliographies for literature and source texts the readers can easily look up literature in the respective bibliography via shorthand while finding all the sources used throughout the work in the separate bibliography.

Minimum Working Example (MWE):

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@unpublished{zschokke_typoskript_1944,
  title = {{Typoskript} der {Rede} anlässlich der {Ausstellungseröffnung}},
  author = {{Peter Zschokke, Präsident des Basler Kunstvereins}},
  date = {1944-03-18},
  keywords = {Quelle,stabs},
  library = {Staatsarchiv Basel-Stadt},
  note = {StABS, PA 888a N 6 (1) 380},
}
@INBOOK{adorno_halbbildung_1959,
  author = {Theodor W. Adorno},
  title = {Theorie der Halbbildung},
  year = {1959},
  pages = {93-121},
  series = {Gesammelte Schriften},
  number = {8},
  booktitle = {Soziologische Schriften I},
  editor = {Rolf Tiedemann},
  publisher = {Suhrkamp},
  location = {Frankfurt am Main},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[%
  bibliography=totoc,
  ngerman
]{scrbook}

\deffootnote[2em]{2em}{2em}{%
\makebox[2em][l]{\thefootnotemark}
}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands,latesthyphen]{german}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[breaklinks,pdfa]{hyperref}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-ibid
]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
  pagetracker=true,
% citation style options
  autocite=footnote,
  citetracker=context,
  ibidtracker=constrict,
  ibidpage=false,
  labeldate=true,
  uniquename=full,
  uniquelist=true,
  sortcites=true,
% bibliography style options:
  dashed=false,
  doi=false,
  eprint=false,
  isbn=false,
  sorting=nyt,
  mergedate=basic
}
%Suppressing of specific BibTeX fields:
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearname{translator}%
  \clearlist{publisher}%
  \clearfield{pagetotal}%
  \clearfield{howpublished}%
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{lccn}%
  \clearfield{annote}%
  \clearfield{language}%
}

\defbibheading{lit}{\subsection*{Bibliografie}}
\defbibheading{quellen}{\subsection*{Quellen}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[%
  strict=true,
  style=swiss
]{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[swiss]{german}[][]%
  {«}[]{»}[]%
  {‹}[]{›}
\hypersetup{%
  hidelinks,
  unicode
}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\section*{Default behavior}
A statement regarding a source text.\footcite[Default behavior: \Frowny{}][1]{zschokke_typoskript_1944} A statement regarding cited literature.\footcite[Default behavior: \Smiley{}][103]{adorno_halbbildung_1959}

\section*{Wanted behavior}
A statement regarding a source text.\footfullcite[Wanted output for source texts: ][1]{zschokke_typoskript_1944} A statement regarding cited literature.\footcite[Wanted output for literature: ][103]{adorno_halbbildung_1959}

\section*{Quellen und Bibliografie}
\printbibliography[heading=quellen, keyword=Quelle]
\printbibliography[heading=lit, notkeyword=Quelle]
\end{document}
\endinput
```

MWE result (footnotes):
[image: Descriptive footnotes to illustrate MWE.]

Software used:

- XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX)
- biblatex 2015/04/19 v3.0
- authoryear-ibid 2015/04/19 v3.0
- biber version 2.1
- Zotero 4.0.28.7

Comment: Welcome! Please post a small, complete document we can compile to reproduce your situation. Obviously, this will need to include at least a couple of `.bib` entries, along with the document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you want. An illustrative example would certainly be of help. Do you want to switch the behaviour of your citation command based on a `keyword`?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes, I want to switch the behaviour of the `\cite` and `\footcite` command based on a keyword of the cited entry. I'll add an MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can branch a `\...cite` command by keyword with `\ifkeyword`

```
\newbibmacro{full:keyw}{%
  \usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifkeyword{Quelle}
     {\usebibmacro{full:keyw}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifkeyword{Quelle}
     {\usebibmacro{full:keyw}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@unpublished{zschokke_typoskript_1944,
  title = {{Typoskript} der {Rede} anlässlich der {Ausstellungseröffnung}},
  author = {{Peter Zschokke, Präsident des Basler Kunstvereins}},
  date = {1944-03-18},
  keywords = {Quelle,stabs},
  library = {Staatsarchiv Basel-Stadt},
  note = {StABS, PA 888a N 6 (1) 380},
}
@INBOOK{adorno_halbbildung_1959,
  author = {Theodor W. Adorno},
  title = {Theorie der Halbbildung},
  year = {1959},
  pages = {93-121},
  series = {Gesammelte Schriften},
  number = {8},
  booktitle = {Soziologische Schriften I},
  editor = {Rolf Tiedemann},
  publisher = {Suhrkamp},
  location = {Frankfurt am Main},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[%
  bibliography=totoc,
  ngerman
]{scrbook}

\deffootnote[2em]{2em}{2em}{%
\makebox[2em][l]{\thefootnotemark}
}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands,latesthyphen]{german}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-ibid
]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
  pagetracker=true,
% citation style options
  autocite=footnote,
  citetracker=context,
  ibidtracker=constrict,
  ibidpage=false,
  labeldate=true,
  uniquename=full,
  uniquelist=true,
  sortcites=true,
% bibliography style options:
  dashed=false,
  doi=false,
  eprint=false,
  isbn=false,
  sorting=nyt,
  mergedate=basic
}
%Suppressing of specific BibTeX fields:
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearname{translator}%
  \clearlist{publisher}%
  \clearfield{pagetotal}%
  \clearfield{howpublished}%
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{lccn}%
  \clearfield{annote}%
  \clearfield{language}%
}

\defbibheading{lit}{\subsection*{Bibliografie}}
\defbibheading{quellen}{\subsection*{Quellen}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[%
  strict=true,
  style=swiss
]{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[swiss]{german}[][]%
  {«}[]{»}[]%
  {‹}[]{›}
\usepackage[breaklinks,pdfa]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  hidelinks,
  unicode
}


\newbibmacro{full:keyw}{%
  \usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifkeyword{Quelle}
     {\usebibmacro{full:keyw}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifkeyword{Quelle}
     {\usebibmacro{full:keyw}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\section*{Default behavior}
A statement regarding a source text.\footcite[1]{zschokke_typoskript_1944} A statement regarding cited literature.\footcite[103]{adorno_halbbildung_1959}


\section*{Quellen und Bibliografie}
\printbibliography[heading=quellen, keyword=Quelle]
\printbibliography[heading=lit, notkeyword=Quelle]
\end{document}
\endinput
```

---

You can of course incorporate this change directly into the `cite` bibmacro, this will then affect all citation commands.

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifkeyword{Quelle}
    {\usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}
    {\global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
     \iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
          {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
              \setunit{\addspace}}
             {\printnames{labelname}%
              \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}
```

MWE (shortened)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@unpublished{zschokke_typoskript_1944,
  title = {{Typoskript} der {Rede} anlässlich der {Ausstellungseröffnung}},
  author = {{Peter Zschokke, Präsident des Basler Kunstvereins}},
  date = {1944-03-18},
  keywords = {Quelle,stabs},
  library = {Staatsarchiv Basel-Stadt},
  note = {StABS, PA 888a N 6 (1) 380},
}
@INBOOK{adorno_halbbildung_1959,
  author = {Theodor W. Adorno},
  title = {Theorie der Halbbildung},
  year = {1959},
  pages = {93-121},
  series = {Gesammelte Schriften},
  number = {8},
  booktitle = {Soziologische Schriften I},
  editor = {Rolf Tiedemann},
  publisher = {Suhrkamp},
  location = {Frankfurt am Main},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[%
  bibliography=totoc,
  ngerman
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands,latesthyphen]{german}    

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-ibid
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[%
  strict=true,
  style=swiss
]{csquotes}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifkeyword{Quelle}
    {\usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}
    {\global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
     \iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
          {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
              \setunit{\addspace}}
             {\printnames{labelname}%
              \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}


\begin{document}
A statement regarding a source text.\footcite[1]{zschokke_typoskript_1944} A statement regarding cited literature.\footcite[103]{adorno_halbbildung_1959}
\end{document}
\endinput
```

---

Both solutions give

[image: footnotes of MWE]